# scheduling using Rufus-scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rufus-scheduler

I using the rufus-scheduler. There is this one function I want to call on every reboot and every 30 mins after that. 
I tried :

```
scheduler.every '30m' do
   .....
end
```

But the first time it does the task is 30 mins after server starts. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the project [README file](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/blob/master/README.md#first_at-first_in-first-first_time), you can use `:first` with `:now` or `:immediately`, which schedules the job for immediate triggering. e.g.:

```
scheduler.every '30m', :first => :now do
   .....
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
def your_function
  puts "I like spaghetti"
end

# ...

scheduler.every '30m' do
  your_function()
end

your_function()
```

It will schedule your function every 30 minutes and then call it immediately.

Comment: As far as I can tell you're the developer of rufus-scheduler, is there a reason you didn't suggest using `:first` with `:now` in this case? I'd have thought that calling the code directly would be obvious though.

Comment: I'm glad you answered as well (+1), nicely completed. My reason is mainly didactic, in a wide sense.